# HTTP Error 502.5 - ANCM Out-Of-Process Startup Failure due to some reason

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, iis-7, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

NET core website it Give me this type of error "HTTP Error 502.5 - ANCM Out-Of-Process Startup Failure"
[image]

Comment: Run a report and the common issues can be found https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html

Comment: Maybe the app is misconfigured due to targeting a version of the ASP.NET Core shared framework that isn’t present. Check what specific version of .NET Core your app targets and install the required runtime version.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of .NET Core are you using?
This problem can be caused by not having the corresponding AspNetCore module installed in IIS (download hosting bundle from Microsoft website: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core). For .NET Core 2.2+ it is AspNetCoreV2.

Also, it can happen if IIS cannot find .NET Core on the machine - you can write the path to it manually in "web.config":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" arguments=".\AppMainDll.dll" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```